# Dojo require() and AMD (1.7)

Tags: javascript, data-structures, dojo, js-amd

I'm having a heckuva time transitioning to Dojo and the new AMD structure, and I'm really hoping someone can shed some light on the whole concept.  I've been living on Google for the last few weeks trying to find information on not the usage, but the structure and design pattern trends in using this.

I find it strange that for a relatively complex javascript application, such as for a main page where Dijits need to be created and styled, DOM elements created, etc, that I need to require, and therefore use, a TON of different modules that were otherwise available in the dojo namespace before the AMD system (or, at least, not assigned to 23 different vars).

Example:

```
require(['dijit/form/ValidationTextBox', 'dijit/form/SimpleTextarea', 'dijit/form/CheckBox', 'dijit/Dialog', 'dijit/form/Form'])
require(['dojo/ready', 'dojo/parser', 'dojo/dom-style', 'dijit/registry', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/_base/connect', 'dojo/dom-construct'], 
function(ready, parser, style, registry, dom, event, construct){
    //...etc
}
```

That's only a few of the modules for one of the pages I'm working on.  Surely there's a better, non-breaking-in-future-releases way of accessing these methods, etc. I mean, do I really have to import an entirely new module to use `byId()`?  And yet another to connect events?  On top of that, all the clutter being created by having to assign a variable name in the functions argument list to cling to just seems like such a backstep.

I thought maybe you would `require()` the module only when needed, such as the `query` module, but if I need it more than once, then chances are the variable it's assigned to is out of scope, and I'd need to put it in a `domReady!` or `ready` call.  *reaalllly....??!*

Which is why I can only assume it's my lack of understanding for dojo.

I really have looked and searched and bought books (albeit, a pre-AMD one), but this library is really giving me a run for my money.  I appreciate light anyone can shed on this.

**Edit for Example**

```
require(['dijit/form/ValidationTextBox'])
require(['dojo/ready', 'dojo/parser', 'dojo/dom-style', 'dijit/registry', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/_base/connect', 'dojo/dom-construct'], function(ready, parser, style, registry, dom, event, construct){
    /* perform some tasks */
    var _name = new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox({
        propercase : true,
        tooltipPosition : ['above', 'after']
    }, 'name')

    /*
    Let's say I want to use the query module in some places, i.e. here.
    */
    require(['dojo/query', 'dojo/dom-attr'], function(query, attr){
        query('#list li').forEach(function(li){
            // do something with these
        })
    })
}
```

Based off of this format, which is used with many examples both from the dojo toolkit folks as well as third party sites, it would be, IMHO, absolutely ridiculous to load all the required modules as the first `function(ready, parser, style, registy...` would get longer and longer, and create problems with naming collisions, etc.

Firing up and `require()`ing all the modules I would need during the life of the script just seems silly to me.  That being said, I'd have to look at some of the "package manager" scripts.  But for this example, if I wanted to use the query module in select places, I would either have to load it up with the rest in the main `require()` statement.  I understand why to an extent, but what's so bad with generic dot-syntax namespaces? dojo.whatever? dijit.findIt()? Why load module, reference in a unique name, pass through closure, blah blah?

I wish this were an easier question to ask, but I hope that makes sense.

**Exasperation**

Call me a newb, but this is really.. really.. driving me mad.  I'm no noob when it comes to Javascript (apparently not) but wow. I cannot figure this  out!

Here's what I'm gathering. In adder.js:

```
define('adder', function(require, exports){
    exports.addTen = function(x){
        return x + 10
    }
})
```

In some master page or whatever:

```
require(['./js/cg/adder.js'])
```

...which doesn't follow the neat `require(['cg/adder'])` format but whatever. Not important right now.

Then, the use of `adder` should be:

```
console.log(adder.addTen(100)) // 110
```

The closest I got was `console.log(adder)` returning `3`. Yep. `3`. Otherwise, it's `adder is not defined`.

Why does this have to be so difficult?  I'm using my noob card on this, cause I really have no idea why this isn't coming together.

Thanks guys.

Comment: You should ask a new question for your followup. You don't have nearly enough code here to show us the problem (for example you don't even define `adder`).

Comment: based on your sample above, you only need two module dependencies, dijit/form/ValidationTextBox and dojo/query, in a single require statement.  Transitive dependencies are taken care of for you.  Like @Domenic says, maybe there's more here and we should start over.

Comment: I'm not? Hmm yea I'll just start over.  Thanks guys. Cheers

Comment: Just read your edited question.  At least from the example you've provided, most of the dependences were entirely unnecessary.  You'd "require" ValidationTextBox, preferably passing a reference back to it rather than using the global dijit.form.ValidationTextBox style reference in your code, and all of those other things needed by ValidationTextBox would be fetched for you, since the loader handles dependencies recursively.   Make sense?  In fact, the way you wrote the code, you may have a timing issue, since you require ValidationTextBox, then use it in the callback of another statement.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The dependency array format:

```
define(["a", "b", "c"], function (a, b, c) {
});
```

can indeed be annoying and error-prone. Matching up the array entries to function parameters is a real pain.

I prefer the `require` format (["Simplified CommonJS Wrapper"](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule)):

```
define(function (require) {
    var a = require("a");
    var b = require("b");
    var c = require("c");
});
```

This keeps your lines short and allows you to rearrange/delete/add lines without having to remember to change things in two places.

The latter format will not work on PS3 and older Opera mobile browsers, but hopefully you don't care.

---

As for why doing this instead of manually namespacing objects, @peller's answer gives a good overview of why modularity is a good thing, and [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164326/whats-the-benefit-of-the-dojo-1-7-amd-framework/9165074#9165074) talks about why AMD and module systems as a way of achieving modularity are a good thing.

The only thing I would add to @peller's answer is to expand on "paying attention to dependencies actually makes for much better code." If your module requires too many other modules, that's a bad sign! We have a loose rule in our 72K LOC JavaScript codebase that a module should be ~100 lines long and require between zero and four dependencies. It's served us well.

Comment: another fun fact - with AMD, code you depend on can actually get garbage collected when your module is no longer referenced.  This doesn't happen when everything is tacked on to a global.

Comment: Also, note that Dojo's loader is asynchronous (uses asynch I/O), so while it supports the "immediate" CJS require signature @Dominic shows here, this variant will *fail* if some other code hasn't already loaded the module.  That's why there's a require signature taking an array and a callback.  As awkward as the AMD dependency array format is, it is designed to simplify the task of loading modules asynchronously.  CJS was designed primarily for server-side systems which did not have the same restrictions as web browsers.

Comment: @peller FALSE. Dojo and other AMD-compliant loaders will use `Function.prototype.toString` to parse out the body of the factory function, then assemble a dependency array.

Comment: @peller Here is the responsible code in RequireJS: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/blob/master/require.js#L1701-1722 Here it is in Noble Modules (which implements CommonJS Modules/2.0, which is also asynchronous): https://github.com/NobleJS/Noble-Modules/blob/1b69a0d7284e9b804488424414b0216fa5ded836/nobleModules.js#L620-644

Comment: I only meant to make the assertion for Dojo.  Does Dojo do this?  I'm aware of how CJS searches the function, but meant to suggest that AMD specifically designed its API to avoid this, accounting for the different, more explicit approach.  In the end, requirejs clearly made a compromise.  Is this part of the AMD spec?

Comment: I couldn't find the Dojo module source code, but if Dojo claims to be AMD compliant, then it has to.

Answer (score 12):

[requirejs.org](http://requirejs.org) gives a pretty good overview of what AMD is and why you'd want to use it.  Yes, Dojo is moving towards smaller modules which you would reference individually.  The result is that you load less code, and your references to it are explicit.  Paying attention to dependencies actually makes for much better code, I think.  AMD enables optimizations, and once the migration is complete, you don't have to load everything into globals anymore.  No more collisions!  The require() block wraps the code which uses various modules.  domReady! relates to the loading of the DOM and has nothing to do with variables being in scope.

Anyway, this is deviating from the Q&A format of SO.  You might want to ask specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll take a look more at requirejs and keep hacking through this.  *Edited original*